# Case select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, inner-join, subtraction

I am trying to create a discount from the total price of an item, this all works but when i get to 'after discount' i get the following error 'Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.'

```
select ma.materialname,
mi.LeadTime,
su.SuppliersName,
'Discount' = CASE WHEN mi.price > 40.000 then (mi.Price / 100) * 10 END,
mi.Price as 'Before Discount',
'After Discount' = Case when 'discount' IS not null then (mi.Price - 'discount') END
from MaterialItem mi
inner join Material ma on mi.MaterialItemID = ma.MaterialID
inner join SupplierDetails sd on mi.SupplierID = sd.SuppliersID
inner join Suppliers su on sd.SuppliersID = su.SuppliersID
```

Im trying to subtract the 'Discount' column from the mi.price column, any help will be appreciated

**EDIT:**

Discount and After discount are not a columns in my tables, i create these on the fly to calculate a discount from the original price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with the query:

First, you are using single quotes around your aliases, those are interpreted as strings not the columns name.

Second, you are referencing an alias inside of your `CASE` statement, you cannot do that. If you want to reference a column alias in the `CASE` then you will need to either use the formula again or place the query inside of another `SELECT` similar to this:

```
select materialname,
  LeadTime,
  SuppliersName,
  Discount,
  BeforeDiscount,
  Case when discount IS not null then (BeforeDiscount - discount) END AfterDiscount
from 
(
  select ma.materialname,
    mi.LeadTime,
    su.SuppliersName,
    CASE WHEN mi.price > 40.000 then (mi.Price / 100) * 10 END as Discount,
    mi.Price as BeforeDiscount
  from MaterialItem mi
  inner join Material ma 
    on mi.MaterialItemID = ma.MaterialID
  inner join SupplierDetails sd 
    on mi.SupplierID = sd.SuppliersID
  inner join Suppliers su 
    on sd.SuppliersID = su.SuppliersID
) src
```

Comment: hi please see my edit for a better explanation, discount and after discount are not table columns, i create these on the fly to calculate a discount

Comment: @Annoscia this query is still doing the same thing. The columns are still being calculated based on the `Price` column